# Multiple Custom Samsung SmartTV Apps

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

Probably wrong place to ask, but ill give it a try.

As the title describes.
I see that the number of custom SmartTV apps are getting larger. I know how to sync a custom\unofficial app to my tv by using a developer account. But the problem is, when i want to add a second custom app, the old app would remove it self. It's as if the IP sync of app only works for a single custom app.

Is there a way to have more than 1 custom app on my smartTV ?

my tv model name: UE55F8005STXXE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that you use Samsung TV 2014 and older, right? Then you have to add all your app into widgetlist.xml file or store all apps into USB stick.

Comment: ah cool. thanks, and yes, i think its an 2014 mod. so where can i read more about this. I mean the app i installed was through the ip, i dont physically have it on pc or stick. How can i download it ?

Comment: If you set some IP address to the TV (for example 192.168.1.1) then you can open XML file in your browser. `http://192.168.1.1/widgetlist.xml` where you can find all available applications. `<download>http://192.168.1.1/Widget/application.zip</download>`

Comment: one more question, i was wondering if you could point me to places where i can find other unofficial apps for samsung smarttv. What i really mean is, is there a comminity\forum etc ?

Comment: I dont know where you find unofficial apps :) May be in the  samsungdforum.com? or some other forums...